# How to empty the file content in vi editor

Tags: linux, command, line, vi

I have a log file on a server called `log.txt` which has many lines. I open the file using the `vi` editor, and I want to empty the file content in command line mode of the `vi`editor. What's the key combination? please help me. Thank you!!!

Comment: You could use  `:1,$d` (delete all lines 1 to the last line). Then to save, `:w`. But you could more easily empty it from the command line of the shell, `> foo.log`.

Comment: `dG` if at start of file, or `1GdG` if not. That's in visual mode, btw.

Comment: thank you very much. dG is the answer I need.

Answer (score 1):

First come out front input mode by pressing `ESC` key then apply `gg` to go to first line and then type `dG` to delete everything .after that save the file with `:w` command that way you will have a blank file :)